# PythonSimpleGUIでのボタンイベントを発動したい

Tags: python

それぞれに設置してある **「閉じる」ボタン** を押して、
ウィジェット自身を閉じることができるようにしたい。

メインウィンドウについては、閉じましたので、問題ないです。

①「キーボードを表示、非表示」ボタンを押して、
keyboardウィジェットを開き、
**「閉じる」ボタン**を押しても閉じません。

②「テキスト入力ウィンドウを開く」ボタンを押して、
text_input_windowウィジェットを開き、
**「閉じる」ボタン**を押しても閉じません。

以上の①、②が分かりません。
よろしくお願いいたします。

実行したら、エラーメッセージがでませんでした。
どこから手をつけていいのか分かりません。
ちなみにコードはIDLEで書いて実行しました。

教えてください。よろしくお願いします。

実行環境:
Windows 7 (32bit)
Python 3.8.10
PySimpleGUI 4.60.4

#### 現状のコード

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

# キーボードクラスの処理
class Keyboard:
    # 初期処理
    def __init__(self, location=(None, None)):
        
        # レイアウト
        keyboard_layout = [
                            [
                                sg.Button("閉じる",
                                          key="close",
                                          size=(4, 2)
                                          )
                                ]
                            ]
        
        # ウィンドウの生成
        self.window = sg.Window(
                                    "keyboard",
                                    keyboard_layout,
                                    keep_on_top=True,
                                    no_titlebar=True,
                                    location=location,
                                    finalize=True
                                )

        # 　アプリ起動時は、キーボードを隠す
        self.hide()
        self.visible = False  # キーボード表示フラグ初期化

    # キーボードウィンドウのイベントハンドラ
    def _keyboardhandler(self):
        # イベントの受付
        if self.event is not None:
            # 「閉じる」ボタン押下時の処理
            if self.event == 'close':
                # キーボードウィンドウを消す
                self.winsow.hide()                    

    # キーボードウィンドウを表示する
    def show(self):
            self.visible = True
            self.window.Reappear()

    # キーボードウィンドウを非表示にする
    def hide(self):
            self.visible = False
            self.window.Disappear()

    # キーボードウィンドウの表示と非表示を切り替える
    def togglevis(self):
        if self.visible:
            self.hide()
        else:
            self.show()

# テキスト入力ウィンドウクラスの処理
class TextInputWindow:      
    def __init__(self):
        layout = [
                    [
                        sg.Button(
                            "閉じる",
                            key="text_close",
                            button_color=("black", "white"),
                            enable_events=True,
                        )
                    ]
                ]

        # ウィンドウの生成
        self.window = sg.Window(
                                    "text_input_window",
                                    layout,
                                    size=(400, 300),
                                    finalize=True
                                )
         
        self.event = None  # イベント初期化
        self.visible = False  # テキストウィンドウ表示フラグ初期化
        
    def show(self):
        self.visible = True
        self.window.Reappear()

    def close(self):
        self.visible = False
        self.window.Close()

        while True:
                event, values = self.window.read()
                if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'text_close':
                    self.window.close()
                    break

# GUIクラスの処理
class GUI:
    def __init__(self):

        self.layout = [
                            [
                                sg.Button(
                                            "キーボードを表示/非表示",
                                            key="keyboard"
                                            ),
                                sg.Button(
                                            "close",
                                            key="close"
                                            )
                            ],

                            [
                                sg.Text("テキストを入力してください")
                            ],
                            [
                                sg.Multiline(
                                                "",
                                                size=(40, 5),
                                                key="-TEXT-",
                                                autoscroll=True,
                                                enable_events=True
                                            )
                            ],
                            [
                                sg.Button(
                                        "テキスト入力ウィンドウを開く",
                                        key="open_text_input_window"
                                        )
                            ]
                        ]

        self.mainWindow = sg.Window(
                                        "On-screen test",
                                        self.layout,
                                        size=(400, 300),
                                        grab_anywhere=True,
                                        no_titlebar=False,
                                        finalize=True
                                    )
         
        location = self.mainWindow.current_location()
        location = location[0] - 200, location[1] + 200
        #self.keyboard = keyboard(location)
        
        self.event = None  # event変数を初期化
        self.keyboard_visible = False  # キーボードの表示状態を管理する変数を追加

        self.text_input_window = None
        self.keyboard = Keyboard()

    def run(self):
        event, values = self.mainWindow.read(timeout=200, timeout_key='timeout')
        while True:
            # イベントを取得
            event, values = self.mainWindow.read(timeout=200, timeout_key='timeout')
            if event == 'open_text_input_window':
                if self.text_input_window is None:
                    self.text_input_window = TextInputWindow()
          
            elif event == 'keyboard':
                self.keyboard.togglevis()

            if event == "close" or event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
                # ユーザーが×ボタンを押した場合
                if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
                    self.mainWindow.close()
                    break
                else:
                    confirm = sg.popup_yes_no("終了しますか？", title="確認", keep_on_top=True)
                    if confirm == "Yes":
                        self.mainWindow.close()
                        break

        # 　各種ウィンドウをクローズ
        self.keyboard.hide()
        if self.text_input_window:
            self.text_input_window.close()
         
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = GUI()
    app.run()
```

Comment: 何か元にした/参考にした書籍/Web記事などがあれば質問記事に書名/章/頁や紹介リンクとかを追記してみてください。ちなみにこんな記事 [hideメソッドやdisappearメソッドを用いてウィンドウの表示・非表示を行う。](https://www.teru2teru.com/python/pysimplegui/screen_transition/#outline__2) のやり方が参考になるのでは？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`run`関数の`while True:`ブロック内でループしウィジェットの入力を取得していると思います
そこで`self.mainWindow.read`だけではメインウィンドウのウィジェットしか取得できません
なので別ウィンドウのボタンには無反応となっているようです
`while True:`ブロックに以下のコードを追加すると`text_input_window`の入力を取得できそうです

```
if self.text_input_window is not None:
    event_1, values_1 = self.text_input_window.window.read(
        timeout=200, timeout_key="timeout"
    )
```

具体的な処理は書いてないのでご自身で追加してください
私は初心者なので思いつきの解答です。もっと良い方法があるかもしれないです。

追記
以下のコードに置き換えることで`text_input_window`の表示、非表示は可能です
(`run`関数の宣言から`elif event == 'keyboard':`の手前までです)

```
def run(self):
    event, values = self.mainWindow.read(timeout=200, timeout_key="timeout")
    while True:
        # イベントを取得
        event, values = self.mainWindow.read(timeout=200, timeout_key="timeout")

        # text_input_window イベント取得
        if self.text_input_window is not None:
            event_1, values_1 = self.text_input_window.window.read(
                timeout=200, timeout_key="timeout"
            )
            #text_input_window 閉じる押されたら隠す
            if event_1 == "text_close":
                self.text_input_window.window.hide()

        if event == "open_text_input_window":
            if self.text_input_window is None:
                self.text_input_window = TextInputWindow()
            else:
                #text_input_window 再表示
                self.text_input_window.window.un_hide()
```

Comment: 後藤喜一様、とても、貴重なご指摘、ありがとうございます。　さっそく、実行してみます！

Comment: いろいろと調べてみた結果、PySimpleGUIでは、この場合は、できないそうです。わざわざ、ご提言をいただいて、とても参考になりました。ありがとうございました。

Comment: すみません、具体的に書けばよかったですね。追記しました。

Comment: 後藤喜一様、くわしく書いてくださって、本当に本当にありがとうございます！！　できました！！　ずっと、悩んでいましたが、おっしゃるとおり　read　のタイミングとwindowをつけることを学ばせていただきました。text_input_window.window.read()なんですね。　本当に助かりました。

Comment: このサイトは、承認というのは、どうすればいいですか？　このままでいいのでしょうか？わかりません。

Comment: 動いたようで良かったです。タイミングというよりウィンドウ毎にreadからevent取得する必要がありそうです。　解答の承認は解答左上のチェックマークをクリックだったかと思います。

Comment: 後藤喜一様、わざわざ。ありがとうございます。